# JPA runs hundreds of selects for a related entity that I'm not accessing

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm learning JPA, and I'm trying to write a little application to display a table with appointments.

For now, I just show the description of the appointment using an `h:dataTable` (JSF) but for some reason, this causes JPA to generate one select per appointment to retrieve the related `Creator` entity. So, for example, if I have 100 appointments, this generates 101 queries to the database (one to retrieve the appointments and one per creator), even if I'm not using accessing this `Creator` entity in any way.

This is my `Appointment` entity. It references the `Creator` entity by a code which is not the primary key, but I can't change the structure of the tables.

```
@Entity
public class Appointment implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigDecimal id;

    private String description;

    private Timestamp date;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "APPOINTMENT_CREATOR", referencedColumnName = "USER_CODE")
    private Creator creator;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

This is the `Creator` entity

```
@Entity
public class Creator implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigDecimal id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    @Column(name="USER_CODE")
    private int userCode;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "creator")
    private List<Cita> appointments;

    public Appointment addAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        getAppointments().add(appointment);
        appointment.setCreator(this);

        return appointment;
    }

    public Appointment removeAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        getAppointments().remove(appointment);
        appointment.setCreator(null);

        return appointment;
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

This is my DAO

```
@Repository
public class AppointmentDAO {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.entityManager = em;
    }

    public List<Appointment> findAll() {
        List<Appointment> result = null;
        try {
            result = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a from Appointment a").getResultList();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is my an excerpt from my log

```
[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.406--ServerSession(33459456)--Connection(11062282)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].

[EL Finest]: query: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.421--ServerSession(33459456)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="creator" referenceClass=Creator sql="SELECT ID, SURNAME, USER_CODE, NAME FROM CREATOR WHERE (USER_CODE = ?)")

[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.421--ServerSession(33459456)--Connection(20248250)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].

[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.421--ServerSession(33459456)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main]) --reconnecting to external connection pool

[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.453--ServerSession(33459456)--Connection(3304058)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--SELECT ID, SURNAME, USER_CODE, NAME FROM CREATOR WHERE (USER_CODE = ?)
    bind => [7054382]

[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.515--ServerSession(33459456)--Connection(20248250)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].

[EL Finest]: transaction: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.531--UnitOfWork(12558692)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Register the existing object net.turbo.model.entities.Creator@b2e368

[EL Finest]: query: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.531--ServerSession(33459456)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="creator" referenceClass=Creator sql="SELECT ID, SURNAME, USER_CODE, NAME FROM CREATOR WHERE (USER_CODE = ?)")

[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.531--ServerSession(33459456)--Connection(32578948)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].

[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.531--ServerSession(33459456)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.562--ServerSession(33459456)--Connection(13173146)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--SELECT ID, SURNAME, USER_CODE, NAME FROM CREATOR WHERE (USER_CODE = ?)
    bind => [7042199]

[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.64--ServerSession(33459456)--Connection(32578948)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].

[EL Finest]: transaction: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.64--UnitOfWork(12558692)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Register the existing object net.turbo.model.entities.Creator@1b0c903

[EL Finest]: query: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.64--ServerSession(33459456)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="creator" referenceClass=Creator sql="SELECT ID, SURNAME, USER_CODE, NAME FROM CREATOR WHERE (USER_CODE = ?)")

[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.64--ServerSession(33459456)--Connection(7112313)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].

[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.64--ServerSession(33459456)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-10-11 16:22:35.671--ServerSession(33459456)--Connection(15764427)--Thread(Thread["http-bio-8080"-exec-3,5,main])--SELECT ID, SURNAME, USER_CODE, NAME FROM CREATOR WHERE (USER_CODE = ?)
    bind => [7076961]



..........
..........
..........
```

Comment: Try to use `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. It was because I was using Tomcat and EclipseLink wasn't able to use weaving to alter the classes, and without this, EclipseLink can only use eager loading.

I just moved from Tomcat to a real application server.

Answer (score 1):

The default fetchType for a `ManyToOne` relationship is `EAGER`.  Set this to `LAZY`, which will cause the `Creator` entities not to be queried until accessed.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "APPOINTMENT_CREATOR", referencedColumnName = "USER_CODE")
private Creator creator;
```

Comment: No. Should I? The entity classes were created using the "JPA Entities from Tables" wizard from Eclipse and it doesn't implement those methods

Comment: @herreria They are not essential for solving this issue but could have been an issue if the `Creator` was used in these methods, since it would cause the association to be fetched.

Comment: if there are no appointments, what is the SQL that is generated in the logs?  Has the query changed at all, or are there exceptions the code is ignoring?